# Iterating through a set of polar coordinates

Tags: tikz-pgf, foreach

This plots five vertices of a pentagon:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\def\Verts{
    {0:1},
    {72:1},
    {144:1},
    {216:1},
    288:1
    }

    \foreach \Vert [count=\i] in \Verts {
        % Draw vertex
        \node at (\Vert) {\textbullet};
    }
\end{tikzpicture}
```

However, this will not and report the error `No shape named {288:1} is known`.

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\def\Verts{
    {0:1},
    {72:1},
    {144:1},
    {216:1},
    {288:1}
    }

    \foreach \Vert [count=\i] in \Verts {
        % Draw vertex
        \node at (\Vert) {\textbullet};
    }
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Why does the last element of the array need to not be enclosed in braces?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The curly braces are not the issue. The issue is an excess space that the parser sees. You can fix this by adding a `%`.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\def\Verts{
    {0:1},
    {72:1},
    {144:1},
    {216:1},
    {288:1}%
    }

    \foreach \Vert [count=\i] in \Verts {
        % Draw vertex
        \node at (\Vert) {\textbullet};
    }
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Alternatively you could use

```
\def\Verts{
    {0:1},
    {72:1},
    {144:1},
    {216:1},
    {288:1}}
```

Again, the excess space is gone. (The other coordinates have a comma right after the closing `}`, so there is no such space.)